# 英語が残っている: ヘルプセンター > 弊社のモデル

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

「ヘルプセンター > 弊社のモデル」のページに英語が残っています。具体的には以下。

- What kind of behavior is expected of users?
- What is the code of conduct?
- Can I support my product on this site?

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: この記事が新しい為、一から翻訳する必要があります。ヘルプセンター全体を考えながら、後日対応します。

Answer (score 2):

> [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

日本語版： [気持ちよく参加するために](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

> [<del>What is the code of conduct?</del>](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240594)
>
> [<del>Be nice.</del>](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240839/314875)
>
> [Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312850/314875)

日本語版：　[行動規範](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct)

> [Can I support my product on this site?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support)

日本語版： [製品サポートとしてこのサイトを使ってもよいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/product-support)

「ヘルプセンター > 私たちのモデル」のページは、現在以下のように表示されております。
[image: Our Model]